# JPA @ManyToMany como traer los objetos relacionados

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jpa

Estoy mapeando dos objetos: Professor y Vehicles, es una relación n a n asi que estoy usando una tabla relación llamada "rel_prof_vehicle". El problema viene a la hora de obtener cualquier objeto Professor o Vehicles, me trae el objeto entero pero en el set de vehicles o professors que tienen respectivamente me aparece el siguiente error:

```
com.sun.jdi.InvocationException occurred invoking method
```

He mirado por stackoverflow y la gente dice que es por el método toString, pero es autogenerado:

```
@Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Professor [professorId=" + professorId + ", firstName=" + firstName + ", lastName=" + lastName
                + ", dni=" + dni + ", email=" + email + ", birthdate=" + birthdate + ", phone=" + phone + ", home="
                + home + ", vehicles=" + vehicles + "]";
    }
```

Además dejo también los mappings. Professor:

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
        cascade = {
                CascadeType.PERSIST,
                CascadeType.MERGE
        })
    @JoinTable(name = "rel_prof_vehicle",
        joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "professor_id") },
        inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "vehicle_id") })
    public Set<Vehicle> getVehicles() {
        return vehicles;
    }
```

Vehicle:

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
                cascade = {
                    CascadeType.PERSIST,
                    CascadeType.MERGE
                },
                mappedBy = "vehicles")
    public Set<Professor> getProfessors() {
        return professors;
    }
```

He estado navegando y viendo mappings de objetos n a n en jpa, pero no he conseguido que funcionen, si sabiesen de algún sitio o de otra forma de mapearlos (igual con ManyToOne) se lo agradecería. 
Antes de que lo pregunten, en la base de datos tengo las claves foráneas de la tabla relación a las de professor y vehicle.

Comment: Bienvenido a SOe. Deberías analizar un poco el stacktrace de tu excepción, para ver qué línea de tu código está dando el error. Y poner aquí esa parte del códido y el stacktrace.

Comment: Error no me da, es solo a la hora de acceder al objeto cuando estoy en el debug cuando me sale dentro del set la notación de com.sun.jdi.InvocationException occurred invoking method

Answer (score 0):

Solucionado: resulta que en los métodos toString(), hashCode() y equals() estaba llamando al método opuesto de la bidirección creando un bucle infinito. He quitado las llamadas a estos métodos en cada modelo y funciona correctamente.